# How to check whether a node exists or not using powershell without getting exception?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to check whether a particular node exists or not like follows.

In my config file there is a node named client ,it may or may not available.

If it is not available i have to add it.

```
    $xmldata = [xml](Get-Content $webConfig)    

        $xpath="//configuration/system.serviceModel"    
        $FullSearchStr= Select-XML -XML $xmldata -XPath $xpath

If ( $FullSearchStr -ne $null) {  

        #Add client node
        $client = $xmldata.CreateElement('Client')
        $client.set_InnerXML("$ClientNode")
        $xmldata.configuration."system.serviceModel".AppendChild($client) 
        $xmldata.Save($webConfig) 

    }
```

The condition i am checking may return array.

i would like to check whether the client node available before or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why can't you just do something like:

```
$xmldata = [xml](Get-Content $webConfig)    
$FullSearchStr = $xmldata.configuration.'system.serviceModel'
```

Answer (score 10):

You can try the SelectSingleNode method:

```
$client = $xmldata.SelectSingleNode('//configuration/system.serviceModel/Client')

if(-not $client)
{
    $client = $xmldata.CreateElement('Client')
    ...
}
```

Comment: The condition succeeds even if 'client' node is there already

Comment: If the xpath is passed as variable like this $xpath='//configuration/system.serviceModel/client' 
 $client = $xmldata.SelectSingleNode($xpath) it fails  , but if i pass the xpath directly then it works fine. Peculiar logic!!! what am i missing MVP?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use 'count' like a boolean

```
if ($xmldata.SelectSingleNode('//configuration/system.serviceModel/Client').Count)
{
 The count is 1 or more, so it exists
}
else
{
 The count is 0, so it doesn't exists
}
```

Comment: That has to be wrapped to get the count. `if (@($xmldata.SelectSingleNode('//configuration/system.serviceModel/Client')).Count -gt 0)`