# Determine XML Node Exists

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

This is probably simple, but I'm trying to determine if a node exists in an XML document. I thought I found an answer in this post,
[How to check whether a node exists or not using powershell without getting exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031110/how-to-check-whether-a-node-exists-or-not-using-powershell-without-getting-excep), but I didn't get it to work. This is my latest attempt.

```
foreach ($vendor in $xml.Vendors.Vendor| Where-Object  {$_.Type -match "Send"}) {
    $NodeExists = $vendor.SelectSingleNode($vendor.EncKey)
    if ($NodeExists -ne $null) {
        # Do something
    }
    else {
       # something else
    }
   }
```

### Edit

Here is XML from my test file. I need to find out if EncKey exists or not for each vendor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- Vendors we will send and retreive files from Get-Send means we will get a file and send them a file Send means we will only send them a file-->
    <Vendors>
        <Vendor Type="Get-Send">
            <Name>Vendor1</Name>            
            <RemotePath>/Remote/Path1/</RemotePath>
            <EncKey>pgpenc.key</EncKey>
        </Vendor>
        <Vendor Type="Send">
            <Name>Vendor2</Name>            
            <RemotePath>/Remote/Path2/</RemotePath> 
            <!-- This one has no EncKey -->         
        </Vendor>
    </Vendors>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a reduced test case for your issue? Something we can paste into our favorite Powershell editor and play with it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that I was using the wrong syntax for SelectSingleNode. Here is a working example.

```
[xml]$xml = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- Vendors we will send and retreive files from Get-Send means we will get a file and send them a file Send means we will only send them a file-->
    <Vendors>
        <Vendor Type="Get-Send">
            <Name>Vendor1</Name>            
            <RemotePath>/Remote/Path1/</RemotePath>
            <EncKey>pgpenc.key</EncKey>
        </Vendor>
        <Vendor Type="Send">
            <Name>Vendor2</Name>            
            <RemotePath>/Remote/Path2/</RemotePath> 
            <!-- This one has no EncKey -->         
        </Vendor>
    </Vendors>
'@

foreach ($vendor in $xml.Vendors.Vendor| Where-Object  {$_.Type -match "Send"}) {
    $NodeExists = $vendor.SelectSingleNode("./EncKey")
    if ($NodeExists -ne $null) {
        write-host "EncKey is null"
    }
    else {
       write-host "EncKey is not null"
    }
   }

EncKey is null
EncKey is not null
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: According to my tests, SelectSingleNode is case sensitive, unless there is a way to change its behavior.

Comment: Good, but should be opposite. if ($NodeExists -ne $null) {
        write-host "EncKey is NOT null"
    }

Comment: An excellent article which simplifies the `SelectSingleNode(..)` implementation, using XML namespaces:


[https://blog.danskingdom.com/powershell-functions-to-get-an-xml-node-and-get-and-set-an-xml-elements-value-even-when-the-element-does-not-already-exist/](https://blog.danskingdom.com/powershell-functions-to-get-an-xml-node-and-get-and-set-an-xml-elements-value-even-when-the-element-does-not-already-exist/)

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way I can think of is to try to write the node value to a variable, and then to see if that variable is null. Here's an example with the standard bookstore xml file.

```
[xml]$bookstore = Get-Content .\bookstore.xml
foreach ($book in $bookstore.bookstore.book | Where-Object {$_.Type -match "novel"}) {
 $NodeExists = $book.author
 if($NodeExists){
  Write-Host $book.author
 }
 else{
  Write-Host 'No Author'
 }
}
```

So for your script, I would think it might be

```
$NodeExists = $null
foreach ($vendor in $xml.Vendors.Vendor| Where-Object  {$_.Type -match "Send"}) {
 $NodeExists = $vendor.EncKey
 if ($NodeExists) {
  # Do something
 }
 else {
  # something else
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. This is along the lines of what I was attempting to do, but if $vendor.EncKey does not exists I get an exception: **Property 'EncKey' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.** and I never get to the "else" part of the statement.

Comment: You can shorten this with "if ( $vendor.EncKey ) {" -- also, this is case insensitive,  as compared to SelectSingleNode which did not work for me.  I did not have any exception issue with this.

Comment: @mack you'll actually get an exception when you have [strict mode turned on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Set-StrictMode?view=powershell-5.0). When the strict mode is turned off, then `$vendor.EncKey` evaluates to `$false` in the statement `if ( $vendor.EncKey )`, as provided by @Jay

Answer (score 5):

Provided you load the $xml object as an XmlDocument using

```
$xml = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xml.LoadXml( (get-content $pathToXmlFile) )
```

Then you can do this, which is much simpler:

```
if ($vendor.encKey -ne $null) {
  # does exist
} else {
  # does not exist
}
```

Comment: Downvote because if the element does not exist an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 4):

Use XPath to select matching nodes. InnerText is searchable by `text()`. You can use `where-object`, or `?` too; behaviour is a bit different. Without sample XML it's hard to be more precise. Use XPath like so,

```
[xml]$doc = @'
<root>
<Vendors>
<Vendor>
<Type>Send</Type>
</Vendor>
<Vendor>
<Type>Receive</Type>
</Vendor>
</Vendors>
</root>
'@

# Xpath query will return a NodeList, even if no match is found
$node1 = $doc.SelectNodes("//Vendor/Type[text() = 'Send']")
$node2 = $doc.SelectNodes("//Vendor/Type[text() = 'Sent']")
$node1.Count
1
$node2.Count
0

# where-object will return $null if no match is found
$node1 = $doc.SelectNodes("//Vendor/Type") | ? { $_.InnerText -eq "Send" }
$node2 = $doc.SelectNodes("//Vendor/Type") | ? { $_.InnerText -eq "Sent" }

$node1 -eq $null
False
$node2 -eq $null
True
```